# « Donne-le-lui ! » — Deux traits d'union ?

Tags: pronoms, orthographe, trait-d-union, impératif

La règle est qu’à l’impératif, les pronoms compléments suivant le verbe sont liés à lui par un trait d’union : *« donne-lui ce ballon ! »*.

La logique impose que lorsque l’on a plusieurs pronoms, comme dans *« donne-le-lui ! »*, on mette plusieurs traits d‘union. Le site [visez juste](http://www.visezjuste.uottawa.ca/pages/orthographe/pronoms_personnels.html), qui est généralement d’assez bonne qualité, semble indiquer qu'on met deux traits d'union dans mon exemple. Cependant, en l’écrivant, j'aurais tendance à ne mettre que le premier, et à laisser tomber les autres (ici, le second). Y a-t-il une règle particulière pour ce cas ? Que faut-il écrire ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Grevisse :

> Lorsque le verbe [à l'impératif] est accompagné de deux pronoms personnels objets, l'un direct, l'autre indirect, ils se mettent après le verbe avec des traits d'union.

Et un de ses exemples est justement :

> *Donne-le-lui*.

En prime, il ne donne pas d'exemple d'exceptions autres que des élisions comme :

> *Souviens-t'en*.

Comment: Tu aurais la référence du paragraphe en question ? J'ai cherché, mais pas trouvé. Le Grevisse est parfois dur à parcourir :)

Comment: 12ième édition, paragraphe 658 (chapitre _Le pronom_, section _les pronoms personnels_, _emploi des formes conjointes_, _place du pronom conjoint autre que sujet_).

Comment: Hihi, j'aurais eu tendance à dire 'souviens-toison' :) En fait, non, dans le doute, je trouverai certainement un moyen de contourner complètement :)

Answer (score 8):

Je cite [un excellent lien](http://www.leconjugueur.com/frtraitunionimperatif.php) donné sur le [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1098/french-language-and-usage) par Evpok tout à l'heure, à propos de l'impératif et des pronoms.

Les [pronoms compléments conjoints](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntaxe_du_pronom_personnel#Cas_de_l.27imp.C3.A9ratif) (éventuellement au nombre de deux, comme dans « donne-le-lui ») sont toujours attachés à leur verbe par un tiret, à l'impératif.
Cependant, il faut souvent faire attention. Dans le premier lien sus-cité, les exemples du dernier paragraphe sont intéressants :

> Viens me le dire. (Tu viens *me le dire*.)
>
> Laisse-moi la regarder. (Tu me laisses *la regarder*.)
>
> Regarde-le chanter. (Tu le regardes *chanter*.)

Il arrive que certains pronoms soient rattachés au verbe qui suit (1<sup>er</sup> et 2<sup>e</sup> exemples), il ne faut alors pas les relier par un tiret au premier verbe.