# Placement of two ("combined") pronouns in French with two verbs

Tags: pronoms, verbes, ordre-des-mots

Is there a grammatical rule for where the "combined" pronouns in a sentence with two verbs (model + infinitive for example) go?

For example, which of the following phrases is correct:

- > Je te le vais donner.
- > Je vais te le donner.
- > Je te vais le donner.

I know, for example, that in Italian, the combined pronouns must either go before both verbs "Te lo devo spiegare" or attached to the second verb "Devo spiegartelo". Does it work that way in French as well?

Comment: Relevant Reddit post: https://www.reddit.com/r/French/comments/3mjyin/in_french_syntax_is_faire_the_only_verb_that/

Answer (score 4):

Personal pronouns always go before the verb they complement.

> Je pense **te** **le** donner sous peu.

The above sentence is about *offering* something to someone.

> Je **t'**ai vu **en** offrir.

Here it's about *seeing* someone, *offering* something.

Your example uses *aller*. It does not admit complements. So it can only be:

> Je vais te le donner.

*Give* something to someone.

However, it becomes a little tricky when [using the imperative mood](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/663/79)…

Comment: Is it really relevant to put *t'* in bold in the second example? I think it's not the same than the first *te*, since we could write: "Je t'ai vu **lui** **en** offrir". *te le donner* means *donner ça à toi*, but the *t'* in the second sentence is not part of the complement which is *offrir ça*.

Comment: The personal pronouns always go before - les pronoms démonstratifs (cela) se placent après.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a rule, that you can find [here](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/315.html).

The order is :

`[sujbect (+ne)]` > `me/te/nous/vous/se` > `le/la/les` > `lui/leur` > `y` > `en` > `[verb]`

This is the verbal group, indivisible.

If your sentence is [Conjugated verb] + [infinitive verb] like "*je vais* + verbal group", "*je pense* + verbal group", "*je t'ai vu* + verbal group", it doesn't change. Order your pronouns for the first verbal group, then for the second.