# Peut-on utiliser deux pronoms à la suite ?

Tags: pronoms, impératif

Raconte cet accident à tes parents ! → Raconte-le leur !

Est-ce correct ? Peut-on mettre deux pronoms à la suite ?

Comment: Qu'est-ce qu'une *rangée* ?

Comment: @Toto « dans une rangée » est certainement la traduction mot-à-mot de *in a raw* = « à la suite » ici.

Comment: @jlliagre: Probablement.

Answer (score 3):

Oui, on peut très bien mettre deux pronoms à la suite mais pas dans n'importe quel ordre et certaines combinaisons sont interdites (ex: <s>je vous lui donne</s>).

> Raconte-le ! : *Tell it!*
>   Raconte-leur ! : *Tell them!*
>   Raconte-le-leur ! : *Tell it to them!*

Les règles d'ordonnancement des pronoms sont décrites [ici](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/315.html).

Voir aussi :

> [Dis-le-lui](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/661/donne-le-lui-deux-traits-dunion?rq=1) ! (*Tell it to him*)

Comment: Tu m'apprends qu'on doit mettre des traits d'union entre chaque mot, merci.

Answer (score 0):

Voici un article qui parle des placements des pronoms afin de savoir comment mettre plusieurs pronoms dans une phrase : https://regardsurlefrancais.com/2016/03/07/le-placement-des-pronoms/

Comment: Bienvenue sur French Language. Les réponses sur les sites de Stackexchange sont censées être explicatives et commentées et pas consister en de simples liens. On peut éventuellement  donner des liens vers une réponse en commentaire, pour pouvoir faire des commentaires il faut avoir 50 points de réputation, ce qui est [vite acquis](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, but it can sound awkward outside of some well-worn usages.  'dis le lui' is perfectly normal.  'apporte la leur' would be awfully weird.